# Saving state of Java applet

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I have a rather complex unsigned Java applet. It (among other things) contains a tree that user can browse. I'm planning to bundle that applet into existing web page, but applet should somehow maintain it's state when user goes to another page of my website.
So, I need your help because i don't know if there's a way for unsigned applet to "sleep" when user navigates to another page of my site, and "go alive" when user comes back to "applet page" offering user to continue it's work (tree nodes that he left selected are still selected when he comes back, etc.).
Is that possible with unsigned applet. If yes - how, if not why? :)

Comment: You could use cookies/files

Comment: Well, cookies can be used for saving state of few controls, but my applet has many, MANY controls (it's more like desktop app then simple web application)

Comment: Then you could make it a desktop app. Or you could write to a file somewhere.

Comment: I think that wouldn't be practical. Is there a way to put whole applet into session, and restore it when user comes back to some particular page?

Comment: Why is this an applet at all?  Why not base the app. around a `JFrame` and launch it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?  The frame can be launched from a link on a web page (like the applet) but is free floating and can withstand the page changing, the tab being closed, or the browser being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since applet is unsigned you have only 2 ways:

1. save state in cookies
2. save state on server

Using cookies from applet requires you to use "live connect", i.e. you will actually call java script of page where your applet is placed to operate cookies. You can save state every time is is changed and read it on applet init.

http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/

If you want you can manage state on server side. For example you can provide RESTful API on server that allows saving and retrieving your state. Then call it from your applet.

Comment: *"Since applet is unsigned you have only 2 ways:"*  You missed the `PersistenceService` of the JNLP API.  (for the OP) Here is a [demo. of the service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).  Good call on the server-side storage, I was mulling this over and forgot that one.

Comment: I never used REST, i don't know if that will have bad impact on performance. My applet is heavily using db, it's already performance impact on it's own...

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, +1 for PersistenceService of JNLP. I did not know about it. Thanks.